# Searching through a 2D array in python 2.7 if a char is in that position

Tags: python, arrays

Hi im trying to search through my array if a particular char is in that position and then printing it to the console.

this is my code so far.

```
students = [['Gary','Y'],['Steve','N'],['Tom','Y']]

for i in range (len(students)):
        if students[i,1] == 'Y':
            print (students(i,0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
for student in students:
    if student[1] == 'Y':
        print(student[0])
```

If you're looking for a one liner then :

```
print [student[0] for student in students if student[1]=='Y']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using indexing correctly.
For python you need to use it as follows:

```
for i in range (len(students)):
      if students[i][1] == 'Y':
          print (students[i][0])
```

Comment: @pissall shows a better way of doing this. But if you want to stick to your code, then you can use what I have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to other answers, you could try using [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) also:

```
>>> students = [['Gary','Y'],['Steve','N'],['Tom','Y']]
>>> filtered = list(filter(lambda x: x[1] == 'Y', students))
>>> print(filtered)
[['Gary', 'Y'], ['Tom', 'Y']]
>>> print([x[0] for x in filtered])
['Gary', 'Tom']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`,

```
filter(lambda i: i[1]=='Y', students)
```

Answer (score -3):

Possibly:

```
students = [['Gary','Y'],['Steve','N'],['Tom','Y']]

for i in range (len(students)):
        if students[i[2]] == 'Y':
            print (students[i])
```

Comment: How should that work? `i` beeing an integer does not allow indexing.

Comment: I dont think you need to use `i` here. A simple `for student in students` loop will work here.

Comment: i is an integer.